Illustrator layer coloring
Sometimes in projects we have to work with 100 plus layers in Ai. Is there any way I can color a group of layers together in AI without going to double click each layer individually?
and also is there any way I can Pick which layers have nothing on it? Like ofter we have to group some certain elements which were in several layers. after grouping I need to delete all those empty layers. but  finding them among 100 plus layers is boring and time consuming.
Thank you

I cant open layers without double clicking in AI 24, for coloring, naming etc.

To change the layer colors/highlight colors.... Highlight the layer or layers you wish to color, or remove color from, in the Layer Panel and then choose Layer Options (or Options for Selection for multi-layer highlighting) from the Layer Panel Menu, and change the highlight color. All highlighted layers will be effected by your choice.
As far as deleting empty layers, I don't think there's anything provided by default. But there is scripting.. https://aiscripts.com/delete-empty-layers-script/

Thank you so much. I am seeing birds flying around my head. now I am so happy.

:O  :O :O  this is so coll. Now I can delete empty layers!!

cool* spelling mistakes bcz am too excited.
